# HTMLAgilitypack and Nuget free?

Tags: html, nuget, html-agility-pack

Your forums advise to use HTMLAgilitypack for reading HTML file in a VS 2010 WPF application. I have downloaded Nuget package to get latest version of HTMLAgilitypack.

**My question is whether these two softwares i.e. Nuget and HTMLAgilitypack are free?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are:

HtmlAgilityPack uses Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL) https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/license

Nuget uses Apache License 2.0 (Apache) https://nuget.codeplex.com/license

Comment: Thanks. The following link also gives insights of Ms-PL licenses.    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/openness/licenses.aspx